# 'Contain is to divide' doesn't imply Dedekind Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, divisibility, ideals, noetherian, dedekind-domain

Let $A$ be a Containment-Division Ring $(\operatorname{CDR})$, i.e., an integral domain that satisfies that for all $I,J$ ideals of $A$ such that $I\subseteq J$, then $I=JK$ for some ideal $K$, that is, $J\mid I$. In some algebra textbooks it is proven that 'being a Dedekind domain' and 'being CDR and noetherian' are equivalent statements.

> Can someone give me an example of a CDR which is not a Dedekind domain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain) refers this (under alternative definitions) to the papers of Gomez-Ramirez. So far, I haven't found an example, but basically we need need an integrally closed non-Noetherian ring of Krull Dimension $1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde will the ring of algebraic integers suffice? It seems to [fit the conditions](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/33/) which you outlined.

Comment: @rschwieb It is integrally closed, and we can consider the ideal ascending chain $(2^{1/n})$ to check it is not noetherian. But, how can we deal with the Krull dimension?

Comment: @Bouzoa [Here you go](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/64843/29335)

Comment: @Bouzoa In fact, for domains CDR = Dedekind. If $J$ is a non-zero ideal and $a\in J$ a non-zero element, then from $(a)\subseteq J$ we get $(a)=JK$, so $J$ is invertible.

Comment: One more thing: "Containment-Division Ring" is a new (and not necessary!) name for "Multiplicative Ring".